# How can I use the desktop version of Google translate on my iPhone?

Tags: macos, ios, desktop, google

The desktop version of Google Translate has features that are not available when using the App on an iPhone (e.g., the phrasebook).  I’ve tried to use  these features by accessing the desktop version of Google Translate on my iPhone via the “request desktop app” feature in both Safari and Chrome without success.

Is there anyway to use the desktop version of Google Translate while on an iPhone?

Comment: If you request the desktop website version and nothing happened, then you can't do anything else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pleasantly surprised to find that the Google Translate phrasebook works fine on iOS using both Chrome and Safari.  Perhaps I got fooled into thinking it was not working because I was not signed into my Google account or because the interface in iOS is so different from the interface for the desktop version.

But the main point is that the phrasebook works in the browser on the iPhone and syncs properly with the phrase book on my desktop computer as long as I’m signed into my Google account.

So the conclusion is: use Google Translate in a browser  if you’re not satisfied with the limited functionality of the iOS app. Not sure why they haven’t made this sync function available for the Google Translate app on iOS; it’s been around on Android for quite some time.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is in the [Google Translate ios app](https://apps.apple.com/hr/app/google-translate/id414706506#?platform=iphone). At least the phrasebook.

Here's [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142480?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en&oco=0) that talks about how to use the phrasebook (save translations) on different platforms.

> ### Save translations - IOS
>
> **Add a word or phrase**
>
> 1. On your iPhone or iPad, open the Translate app.
> 2. Translate a word or phrase.
> 3. Next to the translation, tap Star translation.
>
> **See & delete translations**
>
> 1. On your iPhone or iPad, open the Translate app.
> 2. At the bottom, tap Saved.
> 3. To remove a word or phrase, tap Star translation.
>
> > Note: Your app phrasebook saves on the app only. You won't see it on other devices or in your mobile browser.